# Grafana dashboard snippet for prometheus postgres_exporter

Tags: postgresql

I'm managing a fairly large postgres cluster (15 instances), and aside of the usual dashboard containing a few stats, I was looking for a curated dashboard that could graph the highest number of postgres_exporter metrics.

E.g. https://github.com/wiremind/wiremind-grafana-dashboards/blob/master/postgresql-database.json
Unfortunately this is very basic, and it's hard to get out enough insights out of it.

Does anyone have a repository/snippet that could be useful so I don't have to recreate it from scratch?